# Validate relationship using associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```rb
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property_type
  has_many   :variant_properties
  has_many   :variants, through: :variant_properties
end

class PropertyType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties
end

class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variant_properties
  has_many :properties, through: :variant_properties
end

class VariantProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :variant

  validates_uniqueness_of :property, scope: :property_type
end
```

What I am trying to validate is that two Properties for the same Variant should never belong to the same Property_Type.

Is there any way to perform this validation in a *Rails* way?

EDIT:

Finally solved using a custom validator, as suggested by @qaisar-nadeem. A redundant column would be also ok, but I would consider it an optimization more than a solution.

```rb
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  (...)

  validate :property_type_uniqueness

  private

  def property_type_uniqueness
    unless property_type_unique?
      msg = 'You cannot have multiple property variants with same property type'
      errors.add(:property_id, msg)
    end
  end

  def property_type_unique?
    VariantProperty
      .where(variant: variant)
      .select { |vp| vp.property.property_type == property.property_type }
      .empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: `validates :property, uniqueness: { scope: :property_type_id }`

Comment: I think it is not that @AndreyDeineko. I get this error: `Unknown column 'variant_properties.property_type_id'` because *property_type_id* is in the table *properties*, not *variant_properties*. What I would need is a validator that check through the relations. Btw, your code would be equivalent to `validates_uniqueness_of :property, scope: :property_type_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validates `scope` cannot access joined table so you will need to have custom validation.

So there are two options.

Option 1 : Use a custom validator and have SQL check if there is any Property Variant with same Property Type. 
Custom Validations guide can be found on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Option 2 : Add a redundant  column `property_type_id` in `variant_properties` model and then add `validates_uniqueness_of :property, scope: :property_type` as you already have done

**UPDATE**

Here is the custom validator

```
class VariantProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :variant

  validate :check_property_type_uniqueness

  def check_property_type_uniqueness
   errors.add(:property_id, "You cannot have multiple property variants with same property type") if VariantProperty.joins(:property).where(:property_id=>self.property_id,:variant_id=>self.variant_id,:properties=>{:property_type_id=>self.property.property_type_id}).count > 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution put me on the track. I am a beginner in Rails! By the way, I tried with `.joins` and without and it does perform a subquery in either cases.

Answer (score 0):

your should add relation with PropertyType to VariantProperty

```
class VariantProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :variant
  has_one :property_type, through: :property

  validates :property_type, uniqueness: { scope: :variant_id }
end
```